Laptop shuts off when installing Ubuntu from USB
EDIT 2: I managed to catch a split second error message before the shutdown; turns out it was emergency shutdown due to overheating. I came up with a sneaky solution to avoid opening the laptop.
EDIT: MATE let me boot live in safe graphics mode so I installed it from there thus sideskirting the whole problem. Try or Install still kills the laptop though. No graphics issues on my new install so who knows. Thanks for the help anyway guys
I’m trying to install various flavours of Ubuntu (whichever works, ubuntu seems a bit too much for it). All flavours below are latest versions. Specs: Acer 4741G, i5 430M @ 2.27gz, 4GB RAM, Geforce 310M. Am doing it via bootable usb made with rufus. 2 days ago I got Xbuntu working live on it so today go to install it to hdd: boot from usb, hit try or install in grub, it starts loading but 2 seconds in laptop shuts down. I tried it on my pc and it worked fine. I tried multiple different usb drives got same shutdown, repeated all this with lubuntu and MATE, same thing. The laptop hasn't been touched since I tried xubuntu live 2 days ago as stated above. Thanks for any help

If "another USB" works properly, then use that to install Ubuntu.

I tried three different usb sticks but the same thing happened. I used different usb ports too

If all LiveUSB installers cause power loss, that suggests a hardware fault.

Needs a lot more details. What version of Ubuntu are you trying? What are the specs of the computer? These 2 for a start. Please edit the question and ad this info, not as a comment.

I hope that you can find another ;-) solution of the overheating problem. Maybe an internal fan is no longer working and must be replaced, but if you are lucky it is enough to clean the laptop (blow away dust inside it) or simply put it on a coolpad for laptop computer  with one or more fans to blow cool air into the laptop from underneath.
